# Eigenvalues of product of p.d. Matrix with upper-triangular Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

Let $A$ be a positive definite matrix (positive eigenvalues). Let $B$ be an upper triangular matrix, with ones in its main diagonal (i.e. all its eigenvalues are 1). Is there anything I can say about the eigenvalues of $AB$ ? I would like to find a way to prove that $AB$ has positive eigenvalues, if that's true.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example, where $AB$ has not even real eigenvalues. Consider the positive definite matrix:
$$A =
\begin{bmatrix}
2&1&2\\
1&1&1\\
2&1&3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
with eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = 0.308$, $\lambda_2=0.6431,$ $\lambda_3=5.0489.$ Also, consider the upper triangular matrix:
$$B=\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1\\
0&1&1\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

However,
$$AB=\begin{bmatrix}
2&3&5\\
1&2&3\\
2&3&6
\end{bmatrix}
$$

with eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = 9.3711,$ $\lambda_2=0.3144+0.0885i$, $\lambda_3=0.3144-0.0885i$.